# Updating Oracle Default Profile

Tags: oracle, passwords

I would like to update the oracle DEFAULT profile to use a new PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION.

If I change this, what happens to users that are already using this DEFAULT profile? Will they need to reset there password, or will they go unchanged?

I have no means to test this at the moment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password related parameters of a profile are only checked at the time a password is changed or created.  So changing any of them will have no immediate effect.  The next time a password is changed, the profile will be checked, and the specified password verify function will be invoked at that time.

And FWIW, same thing applies to password expiration.  If password expiration is specified, when a password is created/changed, the user's password expiry date is set per the profile.  Changing the expiration rule in the profile has no effect on existing password expiry date.  They will expire based on the rule in effect at the time the password is changed, then the next time they are changed, the new expirey will be set based on the profile rule at that time.

Comment: Thank you EdStevens. I really couldn't find a clear and concise answer like this. I appreciate the feedback, and it is well explained.